# MS Access Group By breaks when using a date

Tags: date, ms-access, group-by

For some reason using a date/time field in a select query with Group By in Access 2010 breaks (records are not properly "grouped by" the text field first, showing the same "aTextField" value multiple times). I am able to replicate the issue in a simple, one table query. Ex:

```
SELECT aTextField, SUM(aIntField) AS SumOfaIntField
FROM simpleTable
GROUP BY aTextField, aDateField
HAVING aDateField >= Date()
ORDER BY aTextField;
```

As soon as you remove the "aDateField" from the query (Group By and Having lines) then it works properly. I can even remove the HAVING line and it still breaks. Leaving me to believe that it is something with the Group By.

Any feedback would be great. Thanks!

**EDIT** More details

```
**simpleTable**
--------------------------------------------
| ID | aTextField | aIntField | aDateField |
============================================
|  1 | John Doe   |         1 |  3/14/2013 |
|  2 | John Doe   |           |  3/15/2013 |
|  3 | Jane Doe   |         1 |  3/15/2013 |
|  4 | John Doe   |         2 |  3/18/2013 |
|  5 | Jane Doe   |         1 |  3/19/2013 |
|  6 | John Doe   |           |  3/20/2013 |
|  7 | John Doe   |         3 |  3/21/2013 |
|  8 | Jane Doe   |         1 |  3/19/2013 |
|  9 | John Doe   |           |  3/22/2013 |
| 10 | Jane Doe   |         2 |  3/20/2013 |
| 11 | Jane Doe   |           |  3/21/2013 |
| 12 | Jane Doe   |           |  3/22/2013 |
--------------------------------------------

**Expected Result**
-------------------------------
| aTextField | SumOfaIntField |
===============================
| Jane Doe   |              4 |
| John Doe   |              3 |
-------------------------------

**Actual Result**
-------------------------------
| aTextField | SumOfaIntField |
===============================
| Jane Doe   |              2 |
| Jane Doe   |              2 |
| Jane Doe   |                |
| Jane Doe   |                |
| John Doe   |                |
| John Doe   |              3 |
| John Doe   |                |
-------------------------------
```

So what appears to be happening is that there is a seperate row for each date as well. I just need to filter by the date and not necessarily Group By it. However, Access will not accept the query without grouping it. Options?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *breaks*?  Can you post some sample data and the desired result?  Are you aware that your `HAVING` clause it searching for dates in the future?

Comment: @bluefeet I've added details on what is happening. And yes, I'm looking for dates now or in the future.

Comment: Examine the queries @bluefeet and I suggested in Design View of the Access query designer.  Notice you can choose *Where* from the dropdown box in the *Total:* row of the design grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grouping by `aTextField` and `aDateField`.  Perhaps `simpleTable` includes rows where the date is the same, but the time of day is different.  In that case your grouping would produce a row for each date/time combination.

Whether or not that was the explanation, you should check what the db engine actually evaluates by including `aDateField` in the `SELECT` list.

```sql
SELECT aTextField, aDateField, SUM(aIntField) 
FROM simpleTable
GROUP BY aTextField, aDateField
HAVING aDateField >= Date()
ORDER BY aTextField;
```

Also consider using a `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` clause:

```sql
WHERE aDateField >= Date()
```

Based on your sample data, I suspect you want ...

```sql
SELECT aTextField, SUM(aIntField) 
FROM simpleTable
GROUP BY aTextField
WHERE aDateField >= Date()
ORDER BY aTextField;
```

Comment: Any reason why you are keeping the `HAVING` clause and not using a `WHERE`?

Comment: I didn't suspect `HAVING` vs. `WHERE` contributes to the problem he's trying to understand.

Comment: I agree. I am just wondering why you kept the `HAVING` when there is not an aggregate function present in the clause.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that, bf.  `WHERE` makes more sense to me, too.

Comment: @HansUp Correct, the actual HAVING and ORDER BY have nothing to do with the issue in general. It's just part of the statement I'm trying to complete. Also, when using GROUP BY, I think you have to use HAVING instead of WHERE (at least in MS Access).

Comment: Use a `WHERE` to constrain the rows which will subsequently be evaluated by the `GROUP BY`.  It works fine with Access.

Comment: Ok, not sure why that didn't work before, but the WHERE clause works now... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT aTextField, SUM(aIntField) AS SumOfaIntField
FROM simpleTable
WHERE aDateField >= Date()
GROUP BY aTextField
ORDER BY aTextField;
```

You will notice that I removed the `GROUP BY` on the `aDateField` column.  Since you want the total for each `aTextField`, then you do not need to group by the date.  Grouping by date will result in a separate row for each distinct date.

*Note: this query was tested in MS Access 2010 and generated your desired result.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding on how GROUP BY works. You should be seeing the same `aTextField` once for each unique textfield/datetime combination

**Sample**

```
a 2012-01-01
a 2012-01-01
b 2012-01-01
b 2012-01-02
b 2012-01-02
```

**group by aTextField, aDateField**

```
a 2012-01-01
b 2012-01-01
b 2012-01-02
```

**group by aTextField**

```
a
b
```